# How do I can catch and modify XHR JSON response in cypress?

Tags: json, xmlhttprequest, cypress

In Cypress there is possibility to stub XHR response, but I wanted to catch and modify JSON response.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Stub-Responses
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html#With-Stubbing

I do not find a good example that explain this.

In my app there is a call to an API:

**/isHuman**

and response is:

{"isHuman":true}

I wanted to intercept this call and put *true* and another test with *false*

can anybody provide this ?

**Last Edit:**
Testing app in on localhost(where I define baseURL - *localhost:3123*), but there are api calls to a different domain(*https://api.app.com/isHuman*).

I need to change response from that xhr call.

Answer (score 1):

```
 it('modifies the response from the server to insert Kiwi', () => {
      cy.intercept('favorite-fruits', (req) => {
        req.reply((res) => {
          // add Kiwi to the list received from the server
          console.log('original response from the server is %s %o', typeof res.body, res.body)
          const list = res.body

          list.push('Kiwi')
          res.send(list)
        })
      })

      cy.visit('/')
      // check if Kiwi is the last fruit
      cy.get('li').should('have.length.gt', 3)
      .last().should('contain', 'Kiwi')
    })
```

below is the source of the code:

[Partial route mock](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/stubbing-spying__intercept/cypress/integration/stub-fetch-spec.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the same url multiple times inside the same `it()`:

```
it('should od whatever', () => {
  cy.route('GET', '/isHuman', { "isHuman": true });
  /* trigger some requests */

  cy.route('GET', '/isHuman', { "isHuman": false });
  /* trigger other requests */
});
```

Comment: I don't have to use cy.server() ?  I don't know when this XHR is call. Can I place cy.route() anywhere ?

Comment: You do have to use `cy.server()` but it's usually placed to `beforeEach()`

Comment: Hi, similar question but, I want to partilaly mock the XHR response. For instance, in above examle there are many properties in json oblect, without editing them I only want to edit isHuman property. is there any way to achieve that @martin